# ui-router v1.0.0alpha0 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'creationContext' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I started to test out the new ui-router v1.0.0alpha0 with AngularJS v1.4.0 but I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'creationContext' of undefined
    at http://localhost:1828/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:1573:65
    at curried (http://localhost:1828/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:128:24)
    at http://localhost:1828/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:130:21
    at Array.filter (native)
    at matchingConfigPair (http://localhost:1828/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:1587:48)
    at Array.map (native)
    at $View.sync (http://localhost:1828/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:1597:53)
    at $View.register [as registerUiView] (http://localhost:1828/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:1605:15)
    at http://localhost:1828/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3741:37
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:1828/lib/angular/angular.js:8604:9) <!-- uiView: subjects.intro -->
```

Here is my app.config:

```
   var home = {
        name: 'home',
        template: '<div data-ui-view></div>',
        url: '/home/'
    };

    var homeSubjects = {
        name: 'home.subjects',
        resolve: {
            getSubjects: ['subjectService',
                (sus: ISubjectService) => {
                    console.log("getSubjects");
                    sus.getSubjects();
                    return true;
                }]
        },
        url: 'subjects',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'app/subjects/partials/subjects.html',
            },
            'subjects.intro@home.subjects': {
                templateUrl: 'app/subjects/partials/subjects_intro.html',
            },
            'subjects.auth@home.subjects': {
                templateUrl: 'app/subjects/partials/subjects_auth.html',
            }
        }
    };
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this problem or how I can proceed to find out more about the problem which I didn't get in the 0.2 version of the router?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having this error because it tries to find a `ui-view` named `subjects` as parent.

Imo it is simpler to just do this:

```
'intro@home.subjects': {
```

Absolutely targets the `'info'` view in the context of `'home.details'`.

So you can have the following ui-view within `app/subjects/partials/subjects.html`:

```
<div ui-view='intro'/>
```

However if you **do** want dots in the `ui-view` name read this comment from the `ui-router` [source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/e2bdf86a3fbd7369bdd59d9d77fc5fc956f0a7dc/src/view/view.ts#L179).

```
 /*
 * If the ViewConfig's target ui-view name is a segmented name (with dots), then a ui-view matches if:
 * - There exists a parent ui-view where:
 *    - the parent ui-view's name matches the first segment (index 0) of the ViewConfig's target name
 *    - the parent ui-view's context matches the ViewConfig's anchor
 * - And the remaining segments (index 1..n) of the ViewConfig's target name match the tail of the ui-view's fqn
 */
```

So in your case I guess this applies:

```
'$default.intro@home.subjects': {
```

Comment: Thanks I will look into this and update my findings.

Comment: @Marilou any feedback on this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering.  Trying to fix lots of bugs :-) I think it's okay now.  Will try some different things and post another question if still a problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided a JSFiddle example, it's a bit hard to notice an error in your code. However here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847471/angularjs-cannot-read-property-navigable-of-undefined) where the solution is adding the parent state first. Maybe you are using the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

First I would try removing the comma here:

`templateUrl: 'app/subjects/partials/subjects_auth.html',`

..and if that didn't do it, I would try changing

`url: '/home/'` to: `url: '/home'`

and

`url: 'subjects'` to: `url: '/subjects'`

If there was still a problem, I'd:

- Start looking into how your states are being generated from those variables -- I don't see where they are being fed to `$stateProvider`.
- Verify that the parent state is created before the child state.